# How to trim sound files in subfolders by using sox in Mac terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, sox

I have got over 1000 folders, and each folder contains one .wav file and one .txt file ([example of the folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUOal.png)). The text file contains the time interval, and I need to trim the .wav file into clips based on the time interval that each text file given (note that text files are in different folders). I have got the following script from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100477/how-to-trim-audio-file-with-specific-time-from-text-file-by-using-sox-in-mac-ter)

```
#!/bin/bash
index=0
while read this; do
if [ $index -gt 0 ]; then
 sox sound.wav clip-$index.wav trim $start $this-$start
fi
((index+=1))
start=$this
done < times.txt
```

However, it is for single file and it can only be used for files in current directory. How can I make it work for subfolders and into a loop?

Comment: That `done` is the end of a loop that's never started. Have a go with https://www.shellcheck.net/ to find the most glaring errors.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, the shellcheck is quite useful, but you are not really answering my question..

Comment: `done` on its own is a syntax error. You have to pair it with a `while ...; do`. Have a look at [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed one line in my original question, and I have just edited it. But still, how can I make it to work for subfolders..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to do this loop for all the sub-directories. That means that you need to loop over the sub-dirs:

```
#!/bin/bash
topdir=$(pwd)
find . -type d | while read dir ; do
    cd "$dir"
    if [  -f sound.wav -a -f times.txt ] ; then
        index=0
        while read this; do
            if [ $index -gt 0 ]; then
                sox sound.wav "clip-$index.wav" trim "$start" "$this-$start"
            fi
            ((index+=1))
            start="$this"
        done < times.txt
    fi
done
```

I assume that the loop in your question does what you want it to do, and I just added some quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ljm Dullaart. I just changed `sound.wav` and `times.txt` into `*.wav` and `*.txt` ,   but it only worked for the first subfolder, and I got an error message says `line 6: [: too many arguments`.  Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Hi @Ljm, I have just figured it out. I actually just need to execute my trim command in all the subdirs. I just added `for dir in */; do (cd -- "$dir" &&  trim command here) done`. The original answer comes from [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270477/change-directory-and-execute-command-automatically-then-change-directory-back-ou/270494#270494]  by cuonglm.